# Correct way to update django to a specific (but not most recent) version via pipenv

Tags: python, django, pipenv, pipenv-install

I am currently using `django==2.2.5`, managing my dependencies via `pipenv` and would like to upgrade to `django==2.2.15`

Unfortunately the pipenv documentation does not say anything regarding the option of specifying a certain version when using `pipenv update` - hence my problem/question:

Since the command `pipenv update django` would update my django to the latest 3.1 version but I only want to update to version 2.2.15 I have to use `pipenv install django==2.2.15`. True or Not? And if not, what would be the correct way?

Since I am doing this the first time, I am amfraid to mess things up , so just wanted to be on the safe side, before proceeding....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command `pipenv install django=='2.2.15'` to make update to a specific version.